# Installing a package to an alternate location using 'dpkg' without root privileges fails with permissions errors

Tags: dpkg

The command line I am using is

```
dpkg --force-not-root --root  /some/other/location -i the_package.deb
```

but I get an error

```
dpkg: could not open log '/var/log/dpkg.log': Permission denied
```

I would have expected the log to have been written to

```
/some/other/location/var/log/dpkg.log
```

With rpm you can generate an alternate database but I can't see how to do this with dpkg. To get to the above state I manually added (perhaps not the wisest approach) the following.

```
mkdir -p /some/other/location/var/lib/dpkg/updates
mkdir -p /some/other/location/var/lib/dpkg/triggers
mkdir -p /some/other/location/var/lib/dpkg/info
touch /some/other/location/var/lib/dpkg/status
touch /some/other/location/var/lib/dpkg/available
```

If I try to run as root, which I would prefer not to do in this case

```
sudo dpkg --force-not-root --root  /some/other/location -i the_package.deb
```

it gets further and installs the deb in my alternate location but then fails with

```
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute installed post-installation script (/var/lib/dpkg/info/the_package.postinst): No such file or directory
```

but this file has been written by the dpkg command above to

```
/some/other/location/var/lib/dpkg/info/the_package.postinst
```

My reasoning for not using the machines dpkg database is that this is an applications software install to a network drive that is available to a number of users. Perhaps just extracting the contents of the package and manually installing is the best approach. The particular software package does not have any external dependencies listed.

Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.18.2 (amd64)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `--log=filename` to change where you log.

If you are using `--root=/foo` you need to set up `/foo` as a valid root. E.g., `sudo chroot /foo /bin/sh` works.

The "No such file or directory" is indicating that the `the_package.postinst` script requires something that is not in the chroot (most likely `/bin/sh` and a boatload of other things). That is run from within the chroot so you don't see `/foo` in the path.

You could use `--no-triggers` to prevent the triggers from running. However you should now see what a hack this is becoming. `dpkg` is heavily biased toward thinking you want to run the package on the machine on which you are installing it and the root filesystem is at `/`.

"[J]ust extracting the contents of the package and manually installing it will be a better approach." Yes-- it looks like you are installing it on a file server that is not intended to run it.

Edit: Though this strictly solves your problem the "modern" method to distribute software is to use orchestration software (e.g., chef) to install the packages directly on the clients rather than sharing software via a fileserver. Disks are cheap.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like using dpkg is not the right approach for installing packaged software to a fileserver. Thanks for the tip about 'chef'.

Comment: Thanks, that helped, but I must say that mentioning "chroot directory" is confusing. That is because you can't `chroot` as a non-root, but then the question  is about doing `dpkg` installation as a non-root… I get you meant that the destination dir of the dpkg command should be a system that one could chroot into if they wanted so, but it's not obvious one the first read. I think it might help to be explicit with something like "The dpkg destination dir should be a system that one could chroot into if they wanted".